# ASP indirect download fails on android if chrome is used to download file

Tags: android, google-chrome, download, download-manager

i have a problem when downloading a file (indirect download mechanism) from my classic asp application with the android version of the Chrome browser (tested on android 5.01).
The Download first fails and then gets queued ...
It works with Opera, Firefox on Android, iOS and desktop version of chrome.

The difference between all other tested browsers and  chrome is that the android built in download-manager is called to download the file ...

Note: Important for the download is a asp-session, which checks  if the user is authorized to download the file (logged In).

Is it possible that the download fails because it is just starts as Link in the download-manager and the session context is lost?

Has anyone else experience with this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find an answer for your issue?